# Returning dynamic default values from StorageMap

Tags: storagemap

I'm working with a StorageMap and want to return a dynamic default value based on the queried key when the key isn't found. Here's my attempt:

```rust
#[pallet::storage]
#[pallet::getter(fn asset)]
pub(super) type Asset<T: Config> =
    StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, U256, T::AccountId, ValueQuery, GetDefault<T::AccountId>>;

pub struct GetDefault<T>(sp_std::marker::PhantomData<T>);

impl<AccountId> Get<AccountId> for GetDefault<AccountId> {
    fn get() -> AccountId {
        // logic to derive dynamic default value based on asset_id
    }
}
```

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FRAME syntax does not allow for this directly since the key is not passed to the `Get` default impl.

One way to achieve this would be to use an `OptionQuery` and create a custom getter function like this:

```rust
#[pallet::storage]
pub(super) type Asset<T: Config> =
    StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, U256, T::AccountId, OptionQuery>;

fn asset<T: Config>(key: U256) -> <T as frame_system::Config>::AccountId {
    Asset::<T>::get(key).unwrap_or_else(|| {
        todo!("Custom default logic goes here")
    })
}
```

This replaces the auto-generated `asset` getter that you formerly created with
`#[pallet::getter(fn asset)]` and offers a custom default per key.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Oliver Tale-Yazdi. Despite integrating the code you provided, I'm still unable to invoke it from the pallet function using the line: `let result = Asset::<T>::get(asset_id).ok_or(Error::<T>::UnexistentAsset)?;`. Instead of the expected default value, I receive the error.

Comment: Well, you use the getter function now instead of the map: `asset::<T>(asset_id)`.